# how to create putty shortcut to jump directly to chain ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, centos

I have to connect to main server by following commands:

```
ssh user@server1
ssh server2
ssh mainserver1
```

Is there any shortcut in putty or in another tool that I can store the commands and create shortcut to directly logged into `mymainserver1`?

Comment: Have you tried searching online for `ssh chains` because it finds some promising things for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this as:

/bin/bash -c "sudo ssh -A -t server1 ssh -A -t server2 ssh -A -t server3"

Answer (score 0):

You can use MTPuTTY (Multi-Tabbed PuTTY)

This is a great tool when you have multiple sessions open and it allows you to call commands when you log into a profile. 
For example you can call cd /var/www every time you start an SSH session. (Right-click the Putty profile and select the Script tab)

Comment: No cd is simple command you can also do this in Putty

Comment: I see, you can't just type out the three commands as they prompt for a password. Check out this post for ways to script logins: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password)

Comment: no in my case there is no password..  i can login directly..

Answer (score -1):

We used to configure the user ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc with some script when we don´t want to show their the bash.

So U could do the same, create a script with this commands:

```
ssh user@server1
ssh server2
ssh mainserver1
```

Then when U connect with this user it´ll redirect U to desired server.

**EDITTED**

The comment clearly the problem. The script can´t work. An way to call scripts using a Putty session is using PLINK, like this:

plink.exe CentOS_SSH sh script.sh

**CentOS_SSH:** putty session

It runs a script on server using the session, but U would be in the first session, U should to configure their to run a SSH from an bash or another way.

About PLink:
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: how i run this script from putty ?

Comment: This is totally wrong because when first command runs it will logged into first server and script can;t continue .